# Tracking subdomains in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I set up a subdomain and Google Analytics is showing traffic for the subdomain.

However, going into Content section, GA is not showing *pageviews* of the pages of the subdomain. Instead, GA lumps all the *pageviews* in the subdomain.

I checked the code of subdomain pages, and they're all the same as the subdomain homepage.

Here is my tracking code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>try {
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-85']);
 _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain.org']); 
 _gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]); 
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/?scid=a2412a40-1b66-4e0a-a1d5-f5b260de6ee8']);
 _gaq.push(['b._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-56']);
 _gaq.push(['b._setDomainName', 'domain.org']);
 _gaq.push(['b._trackPageview']);
 } catch (err) {}
 (function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();
 </script>
```

Am I missing a dot somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

> ***GA is not showing pageviews of the pages of the subdomain. Instead, GA lumps all the pageviews in the subdomain.***

This is because Google categorizes subdomains as internal links to the root domain, as covered [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/08/reorganizing-internal-vs-external.html), and by default does not show the domain or subdomain in reports.

To solve this using one profile, create a filter as covered [here](http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/):

1. Under `Admin` -> `View (Profile)` -> `View Settings`, click `Filters`.
2. Click `+ New Filter` and provide the *Filter Name*.
3. Under `Filter Type` chose `Custom` and select `Advanced`.
4. Under `Advanced`:
      a. `FieldA` should be set to *Hostname*
      b. `FieldB` should be set to *Request URI*
5. Set the values for both Field A and Field B to `(.*)`, which is an expression that captures all characters.
6. Set the `Output To --> Constructor` option to *Request URI* and provide `$A1$B1` as the value for that choice.

[image]

Alternatively, you can add another profile to Google Analytics for the subdomain, and create a filter to show only traffic for the subdomain:

`Admin -> View -> Filters -> New Filter`

[image]

> ***Am I missing a dot somewhere?***

In the past, it was suggested by Google to use a dot before the domain when including subdomains (i.e., `.domain.org`), however this is no longer advised as can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#domainSubDomains) (under `Traditional (ga.js) syntax`), since the dot causes cookie resets, as covered [here](http://www.roirevolution.com/blog/2011/01/google_analytics_subdomain_tracking.php) (under number 2).