# Creating a filter in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website, www.example.com. I have a subdomain, subdomain.example.com/ that contains all my website's landing pages. Do I have to add subdomain.example.com as a new property in Google Analytics to see my landing pages, or is there a filter I can create under the www.example.com property that will allow me to see the subdomain landing pages (i.e. subdomain.example.com/landing-page)?

Comment: Have a look at this answer:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52424/tracking-subdomains-in-google-analytics/52441#52441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new View under the same Property and apply a Filter to only include that sub domain.

In your Google Analytics Account:

1) Click on Admin button - Make sure that the right property is selected

2) Click Create New View - Third column on the right.

3) Create your View

4) With the sub domain view selected click on Filters

5) Enter Filter Name - Filter Type [Predefined]
 - [Include Only] - [traffic to the hostname] - [that contains]

6) Hostname [sub.domain.tld]

In Classic you also need to go to Tracking info and turn on the sub domain tracking option and then update your tracking code. It will add a line that looks like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
```

Comment: If it's possible, how would I go about setting up the filter?

Comment: I updated the answer with details

Comment: Do you know how I would accomplish this in Classic Analytics? I entered the Filter name, predefined filter, include only, traffic to hostname, that contains, "subdomain.example.com."

When I click verify, I see the subdomain I'm looking for in the column labeled "Before Filter applied." In the column labeled "After filter applied," it only shows www.exmaple.com.

Comment: Ahh... there is one extra step. I added that part to my answer.

Comment: So, going into Tracking Info, I'm not seeing dub domain tracking options. I have to assume that it's turned on and working because I can see my subdomains, I just can't filter by them for some reason. I'm also using Google Tag Manager.